# How to create a conditional node with JMESPath

Tags: conditional-statements, jmespath

With JMESPath based on the following:

- If the input is

  ```json
  { "app": { "usertype": "power" } }
  ```

  I would like to create

  ```json
  { "output": { "aslist": true } }
  ```
- If the input is

  ```json
  { "app": { "usertype": "simple" } }
  ```

  I would like to create:

  ```json
  { "output": { "aslist": false } }
  ```

I can create the output but not the conditional part. Seems like a simple if then else but I can't find any documentation on that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the evaluation of a condition in JMESPath as a value for your resulting JSON.

Given the query:

```
{output: {aslist: app.usertype == 'power'}}
```

- On your example JSON:

  ```json
  { 
    "app": { 
      "usertype": "power" 
    } 
  }
  ```

  This would give

  ```json
  {
    "output": {
      "aslist": true
    }
  }
  ```
- On your example JSON:

  ```json
  { 
    "app": { 
      "usertype": "simple" 
    } 
  }
  ```

  This would give

  ```json
  {
    "output": {
      "aslist": false
    }
  }
  ```

But, of course, since it is a simple evaluation of a condition based on your simplified example it would also give you a `false` for anything that is not of `usertype` being `power`.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great solution. But I now realize that I made the question a little too simple.

Can I also get a value other than true or false as a result, so e.g. "cards" or "lines", or for example omit the node "aslist" completely under a condition?

Another question is whether I can also merge multiple conditions (and / or) in this way, but I will try that myself.

Thank you very much, I was trying a more difficult solution. I kept getting the impression that conditional results were not possible. Do you know a good place where you can find examples of this?

Comment: I kind of suspected something like that to be honest. I am not a 100% sure you would be able to trick JMESPath into giving you orange juice out of a lemon with a condition, is is a query language after all, not a processing one. For the rest, [`and`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#and-expressions) and [`or`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#or-expressions) are definitely doable. Omitting a node should be possible with `[?foo == condition]`, but once again it depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Now, if I were you I'd leave this question be, play a bit with this solution, and when you have reached a new blocking bit ask a new question elaborating a bit more on the use case, and then, bit by bit maybe you'll have what you expect.

Comment: Clear, I think I need a template language for json instead of using a query language. I will have a look at Mustache. Seems more what I'm looking for. Thanks!